# How to add another fragment on the existing fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to create `tab layout with fragments`. When i add another fragment on item click it should show another fragment above it. I am unable to get the goal. Fragment just goes above the existing one but both the fragments content are visible. Please don't throw the link towards any developer page for explanation.

Here is my code

**`home_activity.xml`**

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.example.tabsfragment.School_Fragment" >
            </fragment>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.example.tabsfragment.Sports_Fragment" >
            </fragment>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**`Home_Activity.java`**

```
public class Home_Activity extends FragmentActivity {

TabHost mHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

    mHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mHost.setup();

    TabSpec schoolSpec = mHost.newTabSpec("School").setIndicator("School")
            .setContent(R.id.tab1);
    mHost.addTab(schoolSpec);

    TabSpec sportSpec = mHost.newTabSpec("Sports").setIndicator("Sportss")
            .setContent(R.id.tab2);
    mHost.addTab(sportSpec);

    mHost.setCurrentTab(1);

}
```

**`entertainment.xml`**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I am adding another fragment on `list_item_click` inside `Sports_Fragment`

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Entertainment_Fragment enFragment = new Entertainment_Fragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, enFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Here is the snapshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas/help with explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: *I am trying to create tab layout with fragments* - don't. Fragments as tabs are meant to be added at runtime.

Comment: @Luksprog so what's the way to do it?? Any example plz

Comment: @droid dev I have implemented custom swipeTabs+viewpager not sherlockActiionBar. If you want then i can post here solution..it's easy to implement.but the thing is that you cannot add fragment dynamically.So it is up to you.

Comment: @Pratik Above comment indicates that fragment are to be added at a runtime

Comment: @droid dev sry i haven't implemented the code you want..!

Comment: @Pratik no problem. thanks for looking it.

Comment: @droid dev 1 thing i want to know have you implemented sherlockActioBar in your app?and i haven't tried it yet.because it's hard to integrate in application..so my question is how is this library..i mean is it working nicely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, I think it's worth mentioning...

> "You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a FragmentTransaction"

Please see

[Android: can't replace one fragment with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another)

[How can I show a new Fragment within a single tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894786/how-can-i-show-a-new-fragment-within-a-single-tab)

Here's the solution.

In home_activity.xml, you should leave your tabcontent empty.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Your Home_Activity

```
    private FragmentTabHost mHost;

public void changeFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    EntertainmentFragment enFragment = new EntertainmentFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.tabcontent, enFragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);
    mHost.addTab(mHost.newTabSpec("School")
            .setIndicator("School"), SchoolFragment.class, null);
    mHost.addTab(mHost.newTabSpec("Sport")
            .setIndicator("Sport"), SportsFragment.class, null);
}
```

In your onIemClick (Sports_Fragment), add this

```
MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            mainAct.changeFragment();
```

My full project, which is based on your code, is [here](https://github.com/entryleveldev/TestFragment).

I haven't had a chance to really check why TabHost doesn't work when I tested your code.
But [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup%28android.content.Context,%20android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,%20int%29) works fine for me.

Edit: To fix the overlap problem, you can set OnTabChangeListener:

```
mHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("School")) {
                Log.v(TAG, "school");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                schoolFrag = new SchoolFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.tabcontent, schoolFrag);
                ft.commit();
            }
            if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("Sport")) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Sport");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                SportsFragment sportFrag = new SportsFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.tabcontent, sportFrag);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

    });
```

About the backpress, you can try

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: It's working but when i switch back to another tab, it just overlaps the current fragment on it.

Comment: If i have multiple fragments on a tab, then how to come back to previous fragment using backpress??

Comment: It's working.. But its overlaps if i set `mHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Sports");`. Any idea??

Comment: From my understanding, setCurrentTabByTag doesn't provide support for fragment. (You can check the API source code and you'll see). We have to find the work around...

Comment: Welcome. Sorry that I can't help much. I feel like the ActionBar+Tab API is newer and more flexible.

Comment: Hi i need help regarding the above question. Currently fragments are getting overlayed when i trying to show another fragment in same layout

Comment: can you plz help its urgent??

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429158/fragment-getting-overlapped-on-another-fragment