# android fragment backstack issue

Tags: android-fragments

My layout structure is as follows

```
Layout A
--------------------------------------
|  -------------------------------   |
|  |  Layout B                   |   |
|  |                             |   |
|  |                             |   |
|  |                             |   |
|  -------------------------------   |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
```

Below layout B is another View. 
Layout A contains a fragment F1 which in turn adds a fragment F11 in layout B
Now sometimes I want to replace fragment F11 in layout B with fragment F12 and sometimes I replace Fragment F1 in layout A with another fragment F2
As long as I'm replacing fragments inside layout B it's fine. But the main problem comes when I replace F1 with F2.
Consider the scenario where I have F11 inside F1. Now I replace F1 with F2. Now when I hit the back key F11 is not visible anymore. What is the problem here and How do I go about handling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of nested fragments is undefined, see @hackbod's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: too bad :( guess I will have to change my design