# Fragment - put one into another

Tags: android, android-fragments

is it possible to insert one Android fragment into another? I haven't noticed any information in SDK about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of nested fragments is undefined, see @hackbod's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)