# Multiple fragment instances from XML as pages in a ViewPager - how do add a sub-fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have multiple instances of a fragment that are inflated from an xml file, with an id assigned there that I had hoped to use as a container root.  If I want to attach a sub-fragment to one of these fragments as my container, how do I know which one is used, or better yet how do I select a particular container fragment?  Specifically, I want to be able to attach a fragment to one of a set of pages in a ViewPager, each of which is an instance of a common fragment definition.  Any one of these pages could serve as the root for the sub-fragment.  However, they'll all end up with the same id since it's specified in the XML, and you can't call FragmentTransaction#add using a fragment tag name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to attach a sub-fragment to one of these fragments as my container, how do I know which one is used, or better yet how do I select a particular container fragment?

Android does not support nested fragments, so you simply do not do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use nested fragments - also included in support library
here is my solution
[ViewPager and fragments — design nested fragments or ..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954492/viewpager-and-fragments-design-nested-fragments-or/13413710#13413710)

Comment: great! makes the FragmentPagerAdapter more useful I hope.