# Android navigation and multiscreen support

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm implementing navigation using list navigation mode. 
Currenly i'm have 3 absolutely different and unrelated listviews which can be switched by tapping needed item from navigation menu spinner.
Those listviews is implemented as fragments which is switched by `fragmentManager.replace()` every time when user picks item from navigation menu.

It works now and all was perfect... Until i want normal multiscreen device support.

As i understand the key point for multiscreen support is having separate layouts for different screen sizes. But in this case i can't use this layout in fragment because i will need to nest fragments into fragment container. But nested fragments wasn't supported for a time ago.

To make it more clear, please, look at the schema below

```
MainActivity -> FragmentA -> ListView
             -> FragmentB -> ListView
             -> FragmentC -> ListView
```

If i make FragmentA container with layout depending on screen size then i need to nest original FragmentA into this container, i.e.:

for tablet:

```
MainActivity -> FragmentContainer (also Fragment) -> FragmentA
                                                  -> DetailsFragment
```

for phone:

```
MainActivity -> FragmentContainer -> FragmentA
```

Should i wrap all existing fragment into separate activities and switch between those activities instead?
Or i should use fresh Android Support library with nested fragments support?

What do u think?

Thanks for any help.

Similar question:
[Fragment Tabs and Fragment Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284668/fragment-tabs-and-fragment-activities)

Comment: Are tabs or a viewpager an option for switching lists?  Could you suport several split screens that way?

Comment: I'm currently reading about ViewPager. And found it very useful for this. But i don't wan't page swipes... Can i disable this in ViewPager?

Comment: No, that's the whole idea behind them.