# Use fragments in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to create view pager for a list of objects. Each page is a fragment.

However, on that page, I am also using fragments to display some other data.

I got problem when doing this. I wonder can I put fragments in fragment. Or any other solutions to work this out?

Comment: Nope you've got it wrong. Don't put fragments in your fragments, causes major headaches. Sounds like your smaller fragments "to display data" should be custom views instead

Comment: yo, heard you like fragments so i put fragments in your fragments in your fragments. (credits : xzibit)

Answer (score 1):

Nested fragments are not supported by current fragment implementation (it was answered by Diane, Android engineer as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847770/1235698):

> Nested fragments are not currently supported. Trying to put a fragment
>   within the UI of another fragment will result in undefined and likely
>   broken behavior.

But it does not mean it is not doable - it can be achieved, however requires writing some more code than just fragment. There's comment in same thread by other user:

> I managed this by extending FragmentActivity, FragmentManager, and
>   FragmentTransaction. Basic premise is extend DeferringFragmentActivity
>   in my activities, providing same api so no other code changes. When I
>   call getFragmentManager, I get an instance that
>   DeferringFragmentManager, and when I call beginTransaction, I get a
>   DeferredTransaction. This transaction stores POJOs with the called
>   method and arguments. When commit is call, we look for any pending
>   DeferredTransactions first. Once all transactions have been committed,
>   we start a real transaction and run all the stored methods with args

In general - unless you are desperated, just redesign your layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Fragments cannot hold other fragments.**
It's not supported (errors with state)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Fragments inside an Fragment in a project. The way I ended up doing is adding these inside fragments via code and using the fragment attached to the activity as a "proxy" for the other, so on the oncreateview() of the fragment you instantiate the inside fragments, ondestroyview() you remove the inside fragments and so on.