# Is it possible to add a ViewPager into a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

my code:

```
 public class CustomDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
            /** The system calls this to get the DialogFragment's layout, regardless
                of whether it's being displayed as a dialog or an embedded fragment. */
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.p_product_gallery, container, false);
                ImageView tttiv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.test_image);
                tttiv.setImageResource(R.drawable.baozi);
                return v;
            }

            /** The system calls this only when creating the layout in a dialog. */
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // The only reason you might override this method when using onCreateView() is
                // to modify any dialog characteristics. For example, the dialog includes a
                // title by default, but your custom layout might not need it. So here you can
                // remove the dialog title, but you must call the superclass to get the Dialog.
                mDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
                mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable((new ColorDrawable(0x0f000000)));
                mPager = (ViewPager) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.aa_pager);
                mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);            

                mAdapter = new ProductGalleryAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


                return mDialog;
            }
        }
```

The "mPager" always is null.
Can any one provide an example?
tkx!

Comment: Instead of `mDialog.findViewById()`, can you try doing `getView().findViewById()?`

Comment: hi, @A--C i had try, but its not works,mPager still null, anyother ideas?

Comment: Another thing I could suggest is seeing if in your `onCreateView()` you can get the desired result. Usually, that's where you set everything up. Be sure to use `v.findViewById()` If that returns null too, make sure that your layout actually has a ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using Android 4.2 (and Android Support Library rev 11), fragments are not supported in fragments...

[Fragments within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: However the ViewPager is not a Fragment. I'm thinking the ViewPager should work, and if the OP chooses to use normal Views, they should be alright.

Comment: @A--C It seems that ViewPager can only work with a FragmentPagerAdapter and the return type of getItem() is a Fragment. That means each page in a ViewPager is a Fragment. Am i right?

Comment: @Neo That's the thing. I'd say make an Activity that looks like a Dialog and use Fragments or attempt to implement a PagerAdapter for Views, which is an undertaking.

Comment: @Neo, however like logray says if you are adding the fragments dynamically, this is possible with the latest support library. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments