# error with google maps v2 in tab (MapFragment in Fragment)

Tags: android-tabhost, android-tabs, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have a fragmentActivity where I build a tabHost and in each tab there is a Fragment. Well, I haver four tabs 3 with info and 1 with a fragment where is included a google-map-v2 (is a fragmentMAp in a Fragment because I want to add buttons etc.), when I select one tab and pass to other everything go well, but when I select the map tab, after that other tab and again the map tab an error is throw.

My view seems like:

```
|__||__|__|__|
| __________ |
|| FRAGMENT ||
||_____   _ ||
|| FRAG| |_|||
|| MAP |    ||
||     |    ||
||_____|    ||
||__________||
```

The error:

```
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.monumentos.vistasmovil.MonumentoMapa.onCreateView(MonumentoMapa.java:127)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.monumentos.vistasmovil.Monumento.onTabChanged(Monumento.java:279)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:436)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:421)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:158)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:459)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f06005c, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    ... 27 more
```

The error say:

```
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f06005c, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-29 08:32:56.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    ... 27 more
```

Here is the problem, but I dont know why only this fragment have the problem:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monumenos_view_preview, container, false);


return view;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, I removed the nested MapFragment in my Fragment:

```
public void onDestroyView ()
{
      try{
    SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapv2));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
    super.onDestroyView();  
}
```

I get the solution from here: [Fragments within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: @tato469 i have one question over here? how can i re draw all the marker ? when i get back to the same fragment.