# Android Fragment : replace Crash and Hide/show don't works

Tags: google-maps, menu, crash, android-fragments, show-hide

I'm making an App that implements this [slide-out Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624500/2084450) and i'm pretty much satisfied about the implementation.
I divided my app in multiple `Fragment` for one `Activity` so for each section of the menu there is a `Fragment`.
The point is that i have an `OnItemClickListener` that allow me to switch beetween `Fragments`, so I'd tried two methods :

1. `replace()` : it works fine for all fragment except for one of them that load a XML which contains a map (`code below`). On first load there's no problem but when I switch to another fragment  and came back to the one with the map, the app crash.

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
           android:src="@drawable/refresh"
           android:text="Rafraichir" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements
           OnInfoWindowClickListener, LocationListener {

   ```
   private GoogleMap gMap;
   Geocoder geocoder;

   private LocationManager locationManager;
   private Location userLocation;
   private String provider;

   private ImageButton refreshButton;
   ArrayList<Parking> Parkings;

   Context context;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmen_map,
               container, false);

       gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
               R.id.map)).getMap();
       gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

       context = getActivity();
       geocoder = new Geocoder(context);

       refreshButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
       refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               getParkingsConnection = new GetParkingsConnection(context);
               getParkingsConnection.execute(null, null, null);
               myParkings = new ArrayList<Parking>();
           }
       });

       // Geolocaliation

       LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getActivity()
               .getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
       boolean enabled = service
               .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

       // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
       // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
       // go to the settings
       if (!enabled) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

       // Get the location manager
       locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
               getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
       // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
       // default
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
       provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

       return view;
   }

   private Double[] getLatAndLong(String addresse) {
       List<Address> addresses = null;
       Double latALng[] = new Double[2];
       try {
           addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addresse, 1);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       if (addresses.size() > 0) {
           double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
           double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
           latALng[0] = latitude;
           latALng[1] = longitude;
       }

       return latALng;
   }

   private GetParkingsConnection getParkingsConnection;
   JSONObject json;

   // Non-Statice inner class : connection au serveur
   private class GetParkingsConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       Context mContext;
       private ProgressDialog mDialog;

       GetParkingsConnection(Context context) {
           mContext = context;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

           mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
           mDialog.setMessage("Mise à jour de la carte...");
           mDialog.show();
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

           String resultat;
           resultat = getParkings();
           return resultat;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           Log.d("JSON", result);

           JSONArray jArray;
           try {
               json = new JSONObject(result);
               jArray = json.getJSONArray("parking");

               System.out.println("*****Parkings*****" + jArray.length());
               for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   Log.d("adresse :",
                           json_data.getString("adresse") + ", nom :"
                                   + json_data.getString("nom")
                                   + ", latitude :"
                                   + json_data.getDouble("latitude")
                                   + ", longitude :"
                                   + json_data.getDouble("longitude"));

                   String adresse = json_data.getString("adresse");
                   Double latALng[] = getLatAndLong(adresse);

                   Double lat = latALng[0]; // json_data.getDouble("latitude");
                   Double lng = latALng[1]; // json_data.getDouble("longitude");

                   String nom = json_data.getString("nom");
                   LatLng parkingLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                   Marker parking = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                           .position(parkingLocation)
                           .title(nom)
                           .snippet(adresse)
                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                   .fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker)));

                   Parking park = new Parking(parking.getId(), adresse, nom,
                           "", lat, lng);
                   myParkings.add(park);
               }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           mDialog.dismiss();
       }

       // Fonction effectuant uenrequête de type GET sur le fichier
       // getParking.php
       protected String getParkings() {
           HttpResponse response = null;
           String res = "";
           try {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
               // request.setURI(new
               // URI("http://pkdom.1x.biz/getParkings.php"));
               request.setURI(new URI(
                       "http://glennsonna.fr/webService/getParkings"));
               response = client.execute(request);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               // JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

               res = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

           } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return res;
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Parking parkingToSend = null;

       // TOAST

       /*
        * int p = 0;
        * 
        * while(myParkings.get(p).idMarker != marker.getId() && p <
        * myParkings.size()){ Log.d("Marker :" + marker.getId(),
        * myParkings.get(p).idMarker);
        * 
        * if(myParkings.get(p).idMarker.equals(marker.getId()) ){
        * parkingToSend = myParkings.get(p); Context context =
        * getApplicationContext(); CharSequence text = "Match" +
        * parkingToSend.adresse; int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT; Toast toast
        * = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration); toast.show(); }
        * 
        * p++; }
        */

       for (int p = 0; p < myParkings.size(); p++) {

           Log.d("Marker :" + marker.getId(), myParkings.get(p).idMarker);
           if (myParkings.get(p).idMarker.equals(marker.getId())) {
               parkingToSend = myParkings.get(p);

           }
       }

       if (parkingToSend != null) {
           Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                   ParkingDetail.class);
           i.putExtra("id", parkingToSend.idMarker);
           i.putExtra("adresse", parkingToSend.adresse);
           i.putExtra("nom", parkingToSend.nom);
           i.putExtra("descri", parkingToSend.description);
           i.putExtra("latitude", parkingToSend.lat);
           i.putExtra("longitude", parkingToSend.lng);
           startActivity(i);
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location user) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Log.d("Latitude", ":" + user.getLatitude());
       Log.d("Longitude", ":" + user.getLongitude());
       this.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   ```

   }
2. `hide()` & `show()` : I can switch beetween fragment but excepted for the first screen (the map) all the other show a blank screen without content.

   private MenuDrawer mMenuDrawer;
       private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
       private ListView mList;
       private GoogleMap gMap;

   ```
   private int mActivePosition = -1;

   List<Object> mmyFragment;
   Fragment currentFragment;

   myMapFragment mmyMapFragment;
   myMonCompteFragment mmyMonCompteFragment;
   myPaiementFragment mmyPaiementFragment;
   myReservationsFragment mmyReservationsFragment;
   myFavorisFragment mmyFavorisFragment;
   myCodePromoFragment mmyCodePromoFragment;
   myAboutFragment mmyAboutFragment;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

       ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
       actionBar.setSubtitle("Trouvez votre parking");
       actionBar.setTitle("my");
       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       setupMenu();
       setupFragments();

   }

   private void setupMenu() {

       mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, Position.LEFT);
       mMenuDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

       List<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
       items.add(new Item("Carte", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
       items.add(new Item("Mon Compte", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
       items.add(new Item("Paiement", R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));
       items.add(new Item("Mes Réservations",
               R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));
       items.add(new Item("Mes favoris", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
       // items.add(new Category(" "));
       items.add(new Item("Code Promo", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
       items.add(new Item("A propos", R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));

       // A custom ListView is needed so the drawer can be notified when it's
       // scrolled. This is to update the position
       // of the arrow indicator.
       mList = new ListView(this);
       mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(items);
       mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       mList.setOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener);

       mMenuDrawer.setMenuView(mList);

   }

   private void setupFragments() {

       mmyMapFragment = new myMapFragment();

       mmyMonCompteFragment = new myMonCompteFragment();
       mmyPaiementFragment = new myPaiementFragment();
       mmyReservationsFragment = new myReservationsFragment();
       mmyFavorisFragment = new myFavorisFragment();
       mmyCodePromoFragment = new myCodePromoFragment();
       mmyAboutFragment = new myAboutFragment();

       mmyFragment = new ArrayList<Object>();

       mmyFragment.add(mmyMapFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyMonCompteFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyPaiementFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyReservationsFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyFavorisFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyCodePromoFragment);
       mmyFragment.add(mmyAboutFragment);


       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
               .beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myContenu, mmyMapFragment);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();

       currentFragment = mmyMapFragment;
   }

   private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
               long id) {
           mActivePosition = position;
           mMenuDrawer.setActiveView(view, position);
           mMenuDrawer.closeMenu();

           if ((mmyFragment.get(position) != null)
                   /*&& (mmyFragment.get(position).getClass() != currentFragment
                           .getClass())*/) {

               Fragment nexFragment = (Fragment) mmyFragment
                       .get(position);

               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                       .beginTransaction();
               fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                       android.R.anim.fade_out);
               fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
               if (!nexFragment.isHidden()) {
                   //fragmentTransaction.add(nexFragment, nexFragment.getTag());
                   Toast.makeText(
                           getApplicationContext(),
                           ""
                                   + nexFragment.getClass().toString()
                                   + " : "
                                   + mmyFragment.indexOf(mmyFragment
                                           .get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(nexFragment.getTag());
               fragmentTransaction.attach(nexFragment);
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myContenu, nexFragment);
               //fragmentTransaction.show(nexFragment);

               currentFragment = nexFragment;
               fragmentTransaction.commit();...}
   ```

   ---

After one day i finaly found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624500/2084450)

So i just implemented the code below. But I have to use `replace();` so I'll find a way to save my map state.

```
public void onDestroyView ()
{
      try{
    SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
    super.onDestroyView();  
}
```