# How can you put a ViewPager inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

I have an application that would have 3 fragments. It is defined in xml like this. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/activity_main_large"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_category_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.14"
         layout="@layout/activity_menu_category" />

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.71"
         layout="@layout/activity_menu_fragment" />


     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/orderlist_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.OrderListFragment"
         android:layout_width="167dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/activity_order_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like the middle fragment to be "swipable" where the user will turn pages. So the `com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment` would call a layout that would contain the View Pager

Here is the java file:

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MenuFragment extends FragmentActivity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    static String [] menu_name = {"a", "b","c"};
    static String [] menu_description = {"0", "1", "2"};



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_fragment);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.caesar_salad,menu_name[0], menu_description[0]);
            case 1:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.albondigas_pasta,menu_name[1], menu_description[1]);
            case 2:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.salmon_entrada,menu_name[2], menu_description[2]);
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the layout of the MenuFragment where the viewpager is defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom|top" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:paddingRight="16dp" android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the ImageFragment class :

```
package com.thesis.menubook;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {


      private  int imageResourceId;
      private String name;
      private String namedescription;



    public ImageFragment(int imageResource, String name2, String description) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResource;    
        this.name = name2;
        this.namedescription = description;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_menu, container, false);


        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(imageResourceId);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        tv.setText(name.toString());
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_description);
        tv2.setText(namedescription.toString());

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


            TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
            String mname = tx.toString();   

            TextView tx1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_description);
            String mdesc = tx1.toString();

            EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String q = et.toString();




            }
        });

        return view;

}


}
```

And this is the xml file of the ImageFragment for the content of the pager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="top|bottom|center_vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/caesar_salad" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp" 
    android:paddingRight="16dp" 
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/menu_name" 
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="#2f000000" android:textColor = "@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_description" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/menu_name"    
        android:background="#2f000000"  
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text ="@string/menu_description"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    </TextView>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/add" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="@string/add" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quantity" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quantity" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:background="@android:color/white" android:ems="2" android:inputType="number">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/quantity" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/menu_description" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
        android:background="#2f000000" 
        android:text="@string/quantity" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:typeface="sans"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/viewOrdersList" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="@string/orderlist" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

So from my point of view I think it would work fine because it has good hierarchy I think?

But I get an error like this :

```
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
```

Can't you cast a Viewpager into a fragment?

Here is my LogCat :

```
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.menubook/com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain.onCreate(MenuMain.java:13)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  ... 11 more
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:493)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4132)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
02-14 23:22:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  ... 20 more
02-14 23:22:13.979: D/dalvikvm(399): GC_CONCURRENT freed 328K, 6% free 7419K/7879K, paused 9ms+41ms
02-14 23:22:22.750: I/Process(399): Sending signal. PID: 399 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ViewPager is part of your `ImageFragment` not of your `MenuFragment`(`FragmentActivity`)

You have to set your `ViewPager` in your `ImageFragment` (In your onCreateView with your inflater)

Move your `ViewPager` to `ImageFragment`

```
private ViewPager mPager;
```

And set it with your inflater :

```
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

EDIT after comment : don't change your XML

- You got a FragmentActivity which layout is the first XML you post (where the 3 fragments stand) ===> **So the ViewPager isn't here**
- Each Fragment class is taking care of his own layout on it's own via onCreateView, and return the Fragment to be displayed ===> **It's where the ViewPager is**

Comment: okay I'll try this one. By Viewpager do you mean the viewpager I defined in xml? or the Viewpaged in the java file?

Comment: I trasnferred it but I get red lines on `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I convered it to getFragmentManager and trying it now

Comment: I edit my answer to explain, you're shaking this :) Take a deep breath and read read again the doc for FragmentActivity and Fragment

Comment: Yeah I am really new to Android and I think I should get a tutor or something. I'll keep trying nevertheless

Comment: I am getting an error in the getSupportFragmentManager() when I transferred `private ViewPager mPager;` ` private MyAdapter mAdapter;` and `mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` ` mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);` `mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);` to ImageFragment

Comment: I also transferred my custom adapter `MyAdapter` to ImageFragment

Comment: Np Stackoverflow is here for that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.71"
         layout="@layout/activity_menu_fragment" />
```

com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment extends FragmentActivity . It is an Activity, not Fragment. That is why you get ClassCastException.

Comment: So I just put it as Fragment?

Comment: I tried this but then I cannot set the contentview of my MenuFragment

Comment: I don't think there is an easy change with your current code. Your problem is ViewPager within a ViewPager. For that you need to subclass Viewpager and Override OnTouchIntercept(...), then remove your current "Fragment within Fragment" and change it into a View Or just one Fragment. Which any of these is alot of change in my opinion.

Comment: so what should I remove then?

Comment: or should I define the content of the ImageFragment xml into the menufragment xml? and get ImageFragment to refer to that layout?

Comment: You can try that. It all depends on your needs. But as my previous comment, your current "Fragment within Fragment" [isn't supported.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: I just need it to be "swipable". Is there any approach you could suggest with my existing code?

Comment: Google ViewPager within ViewPager and start from there.