# Fragment not destroyed on rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which is added programmatically. I have however discovered that after a rotation, a new fragment is created but the old fragment is still alive (though not being displayed) I assumed that fragments are destroyed along with the activity on rotation, but this is not the case here. What could be causing my fragment to be retained / not destroyed?
Please note:

1. I am not setting setRetainInstance.
2. The fragment is not added in the activity onCreate (added later when a button is tapped)
3. I can see onDestroy is being called for the Activity upon rotation
4. Although the fragment is added, it obscures the add button and is only be dismissed when I do a "remove".

Code creating the fragment:

```
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "CurrentFragment");
fragmentTransaction.show(fragment).commit();
```

Code removing the fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment).commit();
```

UPDATE:
I cannot confirm if this was the problem, but the fragment registers as a LocalBroadcast receiver in onCreate. It unregistered for broadcasts in onDestroy, but it seems that either the LocalBroadcast registration was preventing onDestroy being called, or onDestroy was not called upon rotation. I now unregister in onStop and this seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Ok when you rotate your device, is that fragment shown? The one that was added by button press?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Yes, the newly created fragment is shown

Answer (score 16):

When the Activity is restarted because of a orientation change, the Android Framework recreates and adds the Fragment automatically for you. 
You probably add the Fragment in `onCreate` of your `Activity`. That's where you add an additional Fragment after the orientation change.

You have to check if the Fragment is already added:

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
if(f == null){
    //Add it, there is no Fragment
}else{
    //It's already there
}
```

Every time you tapp the button that adds the Fragment, a new Fragment will be added. If your container is a FrameLayout you probably won't see it. Try to replace the Fragments:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "CurrentFragment");
```

The method `setRetainInstance(true)` has another purpose. If you enable it, the `Fragment` instance will not be destroyed when the orientation changes (but its Views will be destroyed). That means you can store data in the member variables of a `Fragment` and this data will still be available after an orientation change.

When setting `setRetainInstance(true)` the life-cycle of the Fragment is slightly different. I.e. `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are not called (Because those event do not happen)

Comment: @Hermann I do not add the fragment in onCreate. It is added when the user taps a button.

Comment: Did you press the button more than once before rotating?

Answer (score 2):

Why Cant you replace the existing fragment with new fragment which you want to load.

try this may help you.

```
FragmentNew mFragmentNew = new FragmentNew ();// Which you want to load That Fragment Object 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, mFragmentNew)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment probably save in Bundle object before activity onDestroy(). Try to process removing fragments in onSaveInstanceState():

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //remove here fragments
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Or you can just make Bundle null in onCreate():

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: that `null` assignment would just point the copy of that handle to null. you must mean `savedInstanceState.clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue and i solved it just Replace this line

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "CurrentFragment");
```

To

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "CurrentFragment");
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `Fragment` once at first launch, do it like this:
Following code is copied from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html, comment is mine:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // My Comment: only add when launched for the first time, it won't be null on orientation change
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
        DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not add the fragment in onCreate. It is added when the user taps a button.