# Getting Error while implementation fragment in android

Tags: android

I would like to load different fragment at one `FrameLayout` .This code run when i used simple layout file.But it was gave error at when i made one layout file .My complete code is

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Fragment class is,

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Layout file frag_home is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frg_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_home_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lin_vote"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Vote" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lin_vote"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Vote" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lin_vote"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Vote" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lin_vote"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Vote" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lin_vote"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Vote" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

After run the application it gave following error

```
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     ... 11 more
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-31 07:33:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3751):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: I just noticed in your profile that, even though you got your problems fixed for your previous SO questions, you have never accepted an answer to any of those questions...

Comment: Fragment inside fragment is not supported in xml. If you want to add fragment inside fragment you must need to do runtime from java file xml is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

HomeFragment is inflating a layout that in turn has another fragment. Nested fragments are not supported in versions earlier than 4.2. To know about nested fragments, check [the official page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). And, as stated [there](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments),

> You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes
>   a < fragment >. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a
>   fragment dynamically.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments) answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Nested fragments are not currently supported.  Trying to put a fragment within the UI of another fragment will result in undefined and likely broken behavior.

**Update**: Nested fragments are supported as of Android 4.2 (and Android Support Library rev 11) : http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

**NOTE** (as per [this docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)): "*Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.*"