# Android with fragments, duplicated elements

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building an Android Application (minimum SDK Level 10). When the app is minimized and the user return later to it, the main menu shows buttons and images twice. It only happens when the user uses other apps in the middle, if it happens immediately then the menu is displayed correctly.

Here is the code of the fragment:

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
String mGreeting = "Hello, anonymous user (not signed in)";

public interface Listener {
    public void onStartGameRequested(boolean hardMode);
    public void onShowAchievementsRequested();
    public void onShowLeaderboardsRequested();
    public void onSignInButtonClicked();
    public void onSignOutButtonClicked();
    public void onPlayClicked();
    public void onScoreClicked();
    public void onFeedbackClicked();
}

Listener mListener = null;
boolean mShowSignIn = true;

View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(v==null){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainmenu, container, false);
        final int[] CLICKABLES = new int[] {
                R.id.show_leaderboards_button,
                R.id.sign_in_button, R.id.sign_out_button, R.id.button_play, R.id.feedback 
        };
        for (int i : CLICKABLES) {
            v.findViewById(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
    else {
            ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        }
    return v;
}

public void setListener(Listener l) {
    mListener = l;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //updateUi();
}  

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUi();
} 

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}  

public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
    mGreeting = greeting;
   //updateUi();
}

void updateUi() {
    try{
        if (getActivity() == null) return;

    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(mShowSignIn ?
            View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(mShowSignIn ?
            View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.show_leaderboards_button:
        mListener.onShowLeaderboardsRequested();
        break;
    case R.id.sign_in_button:
        mListener.onSignInButtonClicked();
        break;
    case R.id.sign_out_button:
        mListener.onSignOutButtonClicked();
        break;
    case R.id.feedback:
        mListener.onFeedbackClicked();
        break;
    case R.id.button_play:
        mListener.onPlayClicked();
        break;
    }
}

public void setShowSignInButton(boolean showSignIn) {
    mShowSignIn = showSignIn;
    updateUi();
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I cannot see what is called twice, and I have spent more hours than I would to admit.

EDIT 1: Trying Clint Deygoo solution. Defining View v inside the onCreate is not working neither. This is how I did it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainmenu, container, false);
        final int[] CLICKABLES = new int[] {
                R.id.show_leaderboards_button,
                R.id.sign_in_button, R.id.sign_out_button, R.id.button_play, R.id.feedback 
        };
        for (int i : CLICKABLES) {
            v.findViewById(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
      return v;
}
```

EDIT 2: SOLVED ISSUE. I removed updateUi() and it stopped happening. I am not sure about why it's working, but it is. Thank you all!

Comment: Try bringing View v inside the onCreateView so it's local to that function. Inflate v everytime onCreateView is called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your onCreateView (You should use EDIT 1). It's about nested Fragments.

Raneez Ahmed posted a good answer here
[Fragments within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @adam-wigren. I thought it could lead me to the solution, but I haven't found the way to do it yet. I think that I should not inflate the layout into the fragment, as said here [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments), but how would I setOnCLickListener on the buttons without the view?