# Android Project Fragment Transition throwing Exception when Build target used New API Level 21

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

**Exception is:**

**"Unable to resolve superclass of  L android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;"**

I am trying to Pop the last Fragment Transition from the Fragment Manager's Fragment Back Stack, using the following function:

`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` ,

When I did this, function call throwing following Error. This is only happening when I used New Android API Version 21 as Build target.

Same Code work fine with Older API Version 20.

Error: Could not find superclass of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1'

It seems an Inner Class in the Base class of 'FragmentTransitionCompat21'.

**Error:**

```
W/dalvikvm(1356): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1082)

W/dalvikvm(1356): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed

E/dalvikvm(1356): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter

W/dalvikvm(1356): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 358 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
```

Does anybody find similar Error? please help how to solve this, thank you.

Comment: It is a reported issue about this thing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670 . I'm waiting for an answer too. Btw why downvoted it?

Comment: Thank you for giving the information, will wait for the fix for this issue in API.

Comment: Which support library version are you using? Did you try to update?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely referencing API 21 Version 4 Support Library, if you have any animations set on the transaction that has ObjectAnimator change it, also reference your animations from R.anim, or it will through and error.

Comment: I am not in a position to work on this code, if any one tried this and it is working please tell me , I can choose the answer.

Answer (score 1):

in  few previous days i have also face this kind of err, then i try v7 appcompat with API 22 instead of android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.

have you try this one,

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

there is code snip.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("");
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, Fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I am not in a position to work on this code, if any one tried this solution and it is working please tell me , I can choose the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to pop up fragment from stack inside the fragment you should use getChildFragmentManager instead of getfragmentManager.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments][1]