# Error inflating class fragment: GoogleMaps inside FrameLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to display GoogleMaps inside a `FrameLayout`. This `FrameLayout` is supposed to move up and down according to a toggle button. However, my app crashes when I try to inflate the View.

Is it even possible what I'm doing here? I mean displaying GoogleMaps inside a `FrameLayout`? How can I make this work?

Thank you!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lv_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- this frame is invisible -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_v2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The according code inside my `Fragment` class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView            = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);
    final FragmentManager fm       = getFragmentManager();
    final RelativeLayout fragmentA = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_a);

    fragmentA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RelativeLayout fragmentA = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_a);
            FrameLayout fragmentB    = (FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_b);

            int y = 200;
            if (state == true) {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    fragmentA.animate().translationY(-y).setDuration(500);
                    fragmentB.animate().translationY(-y).setDuration(500);
                    state = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    fragmentA.animate().translationY(y).setDuration(500);
                    fragmentB.animate().translationY(y).setDuration(500);
                    state = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
04-19 15:39:43.248    8758-8758/com.mahlzeit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mahlzeit, PID: 8758
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at com.mahlzeit.mahlzeitactivity.FavoritesFragment.onCreateView(FavoritesFragment.java:27)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're nesting Fragments. You can't have < fragment /> tags in a Fragment layout.

Check here:
[Fragments within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Add the fragment dynamically with [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) inside your Fragment.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie you don't agree? Is there another way?

Comment: Say you have a layout fragment_about.xml and inside it you included a    < fragment /> tag, the Fragment will fail to inflate. You should programatically add a Fragment (beginTransaction(), replace(), etc.) with a FragmentManager inside the containing Fragment.

Comment: @razzledazzle So I'd have another class `MyGoogleMapsFragment extends Fragment` which I add like you said?

Comment: @StefanFalk inside your FavoritesFragment (based on the stack trace) or any containing Fragment, use getChildFragmentManager  and beginTransaction to replace a ViewGroup (for example a FrameLayout) inside the Fragment layout. You don't need to extend it.

In your current case,

`<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
        ..>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_v2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>`