# How can I put three fragments in one fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, nav, drawer

I have a nav drawer set up. I have been using fragments for all of my views and everything works great. My problem is that in one of the fragments I would like to put three other fragments with a listview in each one. I have done a lot of research on this and have found that you can put fragments inside fragments but every tutorial I have tried with no success. If anyone can point me in a direction to achieve this that would be great. If there is another way of achieving this I am open to anything that might work. Maybe a sample of putting three fragments in one fragment would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to have the 3 fragments in one? I faced a similar issue about a year ago and decided instead to swap the 'parent' fragment with an activity so that I was using the framework as I believe it is intended. My first attempt had sub-fragments like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915413/dynamically-add-fragment-into-fragment) but it got pretty hard to manage. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Using of fragments is great, but better to fragmentize you code if you really need to reuse them or otherwise it will be a mess