# Navigate Between Activities Using NavigationDrawer?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So right now I am working on an Android app and I am trying to switch to different activities from the NavigationDrawer. In my MainActivity, I have the nav drawer set up, and a StartingFragment that acts as the main view/activity when the app is first open.

However, I am unable to do this. Whenever I click on any of the list items that I have in my nav drawer, there is no switching of activities. I have looked across StackOverflow and other websites for the solution to my problem, but I can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

Button tea_type;
private String[] navDrawerTitles;
private DrawerLayout navDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_array);
    navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, navDrawerTitles));

       // When a menu item is clicked
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long stuff) {
            final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag;
            // Depending on position, set your fragment
            if (position == 0) { 
                frag = new StartingFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.starting_fragment, frag);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // "Commits" the fragment to the fragment view in the layout
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    navDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    navDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = navDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);

        }
    }

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
/** Starts an Activity when item is clicked*/
private void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0: 
        Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, setSelfTimeActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i1);
        break; 
    }

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I think that the problem may be with this method, because everywhere I have looked there have been comments about the selectItem method. I don't see anything wrong though.

```
/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
/** Starts an Activity when item is clicked*/
private void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0: 
        Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, setSelfTimeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);
        break; 
    }

}
```

Comment: this is definitely do able, I have done this myself on numerous occasions and have just answered a similar question. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312813/multiple-activities-not-fragments-with-a-navigationdrawer-how-to-show-current/27314192#27314192

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same Navigation Drawer on different Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-on-different-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [NavigationDrawer with Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405953/navigationdrawer-with-activities)

> In short, there is no way to use `Activity`s while maintaining the Navigation Drawer, you will have to use Fragments.