# Add Fragment into fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Is it possible to add fragments inside another fragment ?

Indeed, I have an **Activity A** which contains a **fragment F1** and I want to add another **fragment F1.1** in the **fragment F1**.

[image]

How can i do this.

I hope you understand my question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132254/6142219

Comment: This Question has been resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915413/dynamically-add-fragment-into-fragment)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have an activity layout file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.frag.MyFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will create a fragment of type `MyFragment` in the activity, you can also do it programatically:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`R.id.fragment_container` is the id of the view that will hold your fragment in the activity layout file, I normally use a frame layout.

Finally, for the nested fragment you can [only](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2#NestedFragments) do it programatically. The method is pretty similar to adding a fragment to the activity programatically, Inside the parent fragment you do:

```
Fragment nestedFragment = new MyFragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.nested_frag, videoFragment).commit();
```

Once again `R.id.nested_frag` is the id of the container in the parent fragment layout file.

Answer (score 0):

From fragment F1 you can use following to add new fragment :

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```