# Tabbar and Preference page togather in android

Tags: android, tabs, preferences

I am trying to create a settings page for an app, this app require to have a tab-bar at the bottom. I was able to create a Preference page using the `<PreferenceScreen/>` and also created a tab using the `TabHost`. But my problem is that I am not able to figure out how to bring the Tab-bat to the PreferenceScreen page.
I am trying to bring something like this :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it with Tab Fragment, here is a [Tab Fragment in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268361/fragments-in-action-bar-tab-fragments), each one of then must be handle similar to how does [FragmentTabs.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) does it:

```
 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
            if (mLastTab != newTab) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (mLastTab != null) {
                    if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                        ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                    }
                }
                if (newTab != null) {
                    if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                        newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                                newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                        ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                    } else {
                        ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                    }
                }

                mLastTab = newTab;
                ft.commit();
                mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }
        }
```

Then you need to change the style for the tabs on the actionbar, you can check the Styling the action bar or the [styleActionbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarStyle) direcly on the reference, i believe that the [actionBarTabStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarTabBarStyle) is the where you should start customizing.

Also don't forget that the Fragment of the preferences must extend from [PrefrenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)